# Get the sizes of the largest and smallest tables in a database

Tags: mysql

I'm a beginner in SQL and I've been given this command which returns the size of all tables in a given database.

```
SELECT 
    table_schema AS 'Database',
    table_name AS 'Table',
    ROUND(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) 'Size (MB)'
FROM
    information_schema.TABLES
WHERE
    table_schema = DATABASE-NAME
ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC;
```

However, I'm trying to modify it so that the size of the largest and smallest tables in MB are returned.

In my last attempt to get the largest size I have tried this:

```
SELECT 
    table_schema AS 'Database', table_name AS 'Table', MAX(Size)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        (ROUND(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2)) AS Size
    FROM
        information_schema.TABLES) AS subquery
WHERE
    table_schema = DATABASE-NAME;
```

But I got an error (error code 1054) saying that 'table_schema' in 'field list' does not exist.

I know how to use aggregate functions to get the min and max values from a regular column, but I don't see how to do it with an alias column.

Comment: *the size of the largest and smallest databases* Does you mean database (summarizing all ВТ tables) really, or you mean separate tables in your datatbase?

Comment: yeah it was a mistake. I meant the largest and smallest tables in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
SELECT tInfo.table_schema, tInfo.table_name, ROUND(((tInfo.data_length + tInfo.index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) AS `Size (MB)` 
FROM information_schema.TABLES tInfo INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        table_schema,
        MAX(data_length + index_length) AS `max_size`,
        MIN(data_length + index_length) AS `min_size`
    FROM information_schema.TABLES
    GROUP BY table_schema
) tSizes ON tInfo.table_schema = tSizes.table_schema AND (tInfo.data_length + tInfo.index_length) IN (tSizes.`max_size`, tSizes.`min_size`)
WHERE tInfo.table_schema LIKE 'DATABASE-NAME'
```

Comment: Thanks! That did return the size of largest and smallest tables in the database, however, the table names must also be returned, and if multiple table have the same max or min size, they must all be listed.